# MethodCallExpression with IObservable throws access denied exception to System.CoreEx

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, system.reactive

I have a `MethodCallExpression` object from which I'm trying to return a `IObservable<Thing>` instance using the `Reactive Extensions` framework.

```
private IObservable<Thing> GetThing(Expression<Func<Thing>> expression)
{
   Func<Thing> method = expression.Compile()
   var observable = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Thing>(method.BeginInvoke, method.EndInvoke);
   IObservable<Thing> observable = observable();
   return observable;
}
```

The issue is that when this executes I get the following runtime exception on `observable()`:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.CoreEx, Version=1.0.2617.104, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

If I run the method without the Reactive framework everything is fine.

```
 Thing item = method();
```

Any ideas what's causing this? All assembly references are added.

**Edit** I should add that the expression in question contains a method which executes on a Mocked object created using Moq.

Comment: I just tried this with a Moq mock object and didn't get an exception ... so more information about your actual code would be helpful.  But first try the latest Rx build.

Comment: See below, I got this working. It seemed to fix itself after a reboot. Also there was an error in the original implementation which starting giving a more meaningful error after the reboot. I am using the .Net 4 Client Profile which I thought may also contribute to the issue, but haven't been able to reproduce it since despite the same set up and code - very odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to get it working, although I never really got to the bottom of the Access Denied issue. It may have been a reboot that resolved it. After stripping my code right back and rebuilding it I starting getting a different error:

```
The object must be a runtime Reflection object
```

I then changed the code to wrap to method invoke into an `Action` before applying Rx, and this worked:

```
private IObservable<Thing> GetThing(Expression<Func<Thing>> expression)
{
   var method = expression.Compile();
   Func<Thing> = () => method();
   var observable = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Thing>(method.BeginInvoke, method.EndInvoke);
   return observable();
}
```

For the record I was able to reduce this further:

```
private IObservable<Thing> GetThing(Expression<Func<Thing>> expression)
{
   var method = expression.Compile();
   Func<Thing> action = () => method();
   return Observable.Start(action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is reactive framework installed for the current user? do you have read/executable access to this file?

Comment: Yes I'm using the reactive framework fine on it's own, it's only in this context.